# "The first one" vs. "The first"

Tags: sentence-structure, reference

Can anyone explain the difference between using **first one** and **first**, when referencing nouns from a previous sentence? Consider the following two cases:

> **Case 1:**
>   There are two primary noise source categories.
>   The first represents the intrinsic noise, while the second refers to ...
>
> **Case 2:**
>   There are two primary noise source categories.
>   The first **one** represents the intrinsic noise, while the second **one** refers to ...

Are both proper ways of referencing the two categories of noise source?

Comment: All 4 permutations are valid and idiomatic (you can include optional ***one*** in either, both, or neither case, after ***first*** and ***second***).

Comment: Without the _one_ sounds more polished.

Comment: I'd use 'one' and 'the other' as there seems little reason to order the categories in terms of fundamentalness, importance, or time.

Comment: This may just be a personal bugbear, but I really dislike *two primary* anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning *prima facie* is identical.

The "one" is implied.

- The **first** represents the intrinsic noise, the **second** refers to ...
- The **first one** represents the intrinsic noise, the **second one** refers to ...
- The **first category** represents the intrinsic noise,  the **second category** refers to...
- The **first noise category** represents the intrinsic noise,  the **second noise category** refers to...
- The **first one** represents the intrinsic noise, the **latter one** refers to...
- The **first** represents the intrinsic noise, the **latter** refers to...

They all mean the same thing and are equally valid.

Now post a question about "represents" vs "refers to" :-)

Comment: Thanks for such complete answer! What should I observe about those two? hehe